# How to get data from a table inside a while loop from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

The `user_id` can be found on the `replies` table but also in the `profiles` table. The profiles table has the `real_name` column.

Below I get all the `replie`s for a specific `article_id`. My question is how do I echo the `real_name` of the commenters that is saved into the `profiles` table ?

I am consider the performance of this.

```
$replies = mysql_query("select * from replies where article_id = '$row[id]' order by timestamp desc");

while($reply = mysql_fetch_assoc($replies)) {

I can echo the comments from the replies table, but how do I echo the real_name of each?

}
```

Comment: Join the profiles table? Something like `select p.real_name, r.* from replies as r
join profiles as p
on r.profileid = p.profileid
where article_id = '$row[id]' order by timestamp desc` might have to update the`profileid` column names

Comment: Also have a look at either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) functions were deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try That :

```
$replies = mysql_query("select * from replies,profiles where article_id = '$row[id]' AND replies.user_id=profiles.id order by timestamp desc");
```

Good luck !